# How To Compare 2 lists of Strings using for each

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through 2 lists using this code

```
foreach (string str1 in list<string>tags)
{ 
    foreach (string str2 in list<string>ArchivedInformation) { }
}
```

The first list has tags which is stored as "tag1, tag2,tag3.." and the second list has information stored as "tag1, Datestamp, 0.01","tag2, datestamp, 0.02" and so on.

I would like to ask how can I get the Tags in the second list and use it as a condition to my first for each? I have tried splitting the second list but i am cannot get the exact "Tag1" as an id to use it as a condition.

In the end the goal I would want to do is `Str1(from tags list) == Str2(From Archivedinformation)`.

Comment: Have you considered using a Dictionary?

Comment: I Haven't, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just Want to know, is this doable using just only Dictionary? or it can be done using a list as well

Comment: Are you familiar with Dictionaries? It's a data structure that contains a list of keys and associated values. I would structure your data so the tags are dictionary keys and the ArchivedInformation values are the dictionary values. You wouldn't need to have the tag in the value, so it would just be like "Datestamp, 0.01". You could use a Dictionary<string, List<string>>. I'm not really sure I understand what you are actually trying to do with your foreach loop, though. It seems like you are just trying to associate the data, and if you weren't using two lists you might not even need to.

Comment: Yes i am actually accessing 2 lists at the same time as it is the current design of the system. but definitely a dictionary is something i need to look at its just that their preference is to access 2 lists and compare the id's on both of them. much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Everything's possible. Other thing is if it's even sane :)

```
    public void Something()
    {
        // Using Dictionary
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("tag1", "tag1,datestamp,0.01");
        dict.Add("tag2", "tag2,datestamp,0.02");

        // out -> "tag2,datestamp,0.02"            
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dict["tag2"]);    


        // Using two separate lists
        var tags = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag2" };
        var infos = new List<string> { "tag1,datestamp,0.01", "tag2,datestamp,0.02" };

        // out ->  tag1,datestamp,0.01 & tag2,datestamp,0.02
        tags.ForEach(tag =>
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                infos.First(info => info.StartsWith(tag)))); 
    }
```

Comment: thanks! i tried to use this function as well

 string cmp;
 cmp = str2.Substring(0,str2.IndexOf(','));